# Failing to reach my app locally (route doesn't work)

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've built a deployment, service and ingress however I fail to reach it on my local web (using minikube).

I've just uploaded a random HTML to my github user, and this "app" is just cloning my git repo containing the HTML file to the container and I try to reach it locally..

**My Deployment file: (My container is working well 100%).**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: test-deployment
  labels: 
    app: nginx
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers: 
      - name: ourapp
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cdn
          mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
      initContainers:
      - name: init
        image: alpine/git:latest
        volumeMounts:
        - name: cdn
          mountPath: /home/cdn
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args: ['git clone $GIT_CLONE /home/cdn']
        env:
          - name: GIT_CLONE
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: config-map
                key: kvsource
      volumes:
      - name: cdn
        emptyDir: {}
```

**My service file:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-cip-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
```

**I've applied the ingress addon on Minikube and generated the following ingress file:**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: my-cip-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

**However I still unable to reach my app at localhost/    address..
I'm stuck on it for a long time.. Do you see anything wrong here?**

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I think, you need to change your service `targetPort` to 80. Secondly, while working on minikube, you need to setup a entry in your system's `hosts` file with ingress host (`localhost` in your case) pointing to the minikube node ip.

As you're just testing, change ingress host to something like `example.com` for your own clarity. And you can get the node ip by just typing `minikube ip`. So, create an entry for `example.com` pointing to `minikube ip` and try hitting `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

When using minikube it does not mean that your applications will be accessible on localhost.

When ingress addon is enabled for minikube, you can reach it (ingress controller) under minikube VM ip.

You can get this ip by running `minikube ip` command.

If you want to use your own domain locally (assuming you run on linux or mac) run:

```
sudo sh -c "echo $(minikube ip) domain.test >> /etc/hosts"
```

It will add one line to you hosts file pointing domain.test to minikube ip.

Now you can use this domain in your ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: domain.test    # <- HERE ->
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service: 
            name: my-cip-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

---

Additionally, you have a misconfigured service. TargetPort field should be set to the port number that the application is listening on. As far as I know, nginx image listens on port 80 by default and so targetPort of associated service should be set to this value.

From now on you should be able to reach your website locally under http://domain.test.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!
I'm using Windows OS with WSL .. so adding minikube IP on the ubuntu WSL will let me reach or I have to configure something extra on my Windows OS hosts file ?

Comment: I dont know much about wsl but i've found that if you were to open `/etc/hosts` file in wsl you should see: `"This file is automatically generated by WSL based on the Windows hosts file:  %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. Modifications to this file will be overwritten."`. So just edit the `%WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file in windows and add the domain there.

Comment: That's weird, I'm still unable to reach domain.test after adding it in my hosts file..